# want to upgrade application over the air

Tags: java-me, installation, upgrade

I have implemented following code to upgrade application

```
platformrequest("URL TO JAR FILE");
```

I am checking if the jad file residing on server has more value in the custom field Application-Version than the current one then the platformRequest will get called.

every thing fine

but only one problem I have installed my app in memory card and if I updateusing above mentioned technique.
I am having new version installed saperately..

instead of this I want my older version application to be upgraded [replaced by newer]

in jad file ony I change the Application-Version Field rest every thing are same as the local installed appliction..

and I want my app to be replaced in memory card only.

Answer (score 0):

what phone are we talking about?

In essence it should not matter where the app is located, it should update.

Make sure the platform request should point to the jad of course

Comment: i am talking about Nokia 3110-c
i am downloading it from my server. and obviously i'd point to jad file..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be using a custom field/attribute for this.

Are you using the `MIDlet-Version` attribute in your application's manifest/JAD file? This attribute is used by a device's AMS (application management software) to determine if your pointing to a newer version.

[See here for a description of the standard MIDlet attributes.](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2001/04/26/midlet.html)

Comment: Yes I have updated midlet-version also and ofcourse i am pointing to jad only..
phone is Nokia 3110c